# What is the difference between these Java environment variables?

Tags: java, command-line, configuration, jvm, environment

What is the difference between the Java environment variables `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, `JAVA_OPTIONS`, `_JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`, `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`, `_JAVA_OPTS`, and `JAVA_OPTS`?  When is each one supposed to be used?  Are these a standard part of the spec for all JVMs, or do they only apply to Oracle's JVMs?

Comment: I never use any of them and I'm not aware that any of them apply to Oracle JVMs. I've seen some of them used in Tomcat startup scripts. You need to disclose to us the context(s) in which you have encountered these things.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else gets stranded on this old post because of a Google search...

From a comment in **OpenJDK** [source code, as of Java 11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/VM.java)

```
 * @implNote
 * The HotSpot JVM processes the input arguments from multiple sources
 * in the following order:
 * 1. JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable
 * 2. Options from JNI Invocation API
 * 3. _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable
 *
 * If VM options file is specified via -XX:VMOptionsFile, the vm options
 * file is read and expanded in place of -XX:VMOptionFile option.
```

And from a comment of the [matching unit tests](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/test/hotspot/jtreg/runtime/CommandLine/VMOptionsFile/TestVMOptionsFile.java)

```
     * Here is the order of options processing and last argument wins:
     *    1) Flags file
     *    2) JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variables
     *    3) Pseudo command line from launcher
     *    4) _JAVA_OPTIONS
     * In every category arguments processed from left to right and from up to down
     * and the last processed arguments wins, i.e. if argument is defined several
     * times the value of argument will be equal to the last processed argument.
```

Note that "Flag files" are passed on the command line via `-XX:VMOptionsFile=` in that test.
Note also the *pseudo* qualifier in "pseudo command line" refers to the way the unit test generates the command line; for the JVM being tested they are not different from *actual* command line options.

Elsewhere in that repo it is hinted that `_JAVA_OPTIONS` was introduced for testing/debugging purposes.

---

Bottom line: if you are an Ops in charge of a canned Java app running on top of OpenJDK, and need to set/override some Java properties, but cannot do that via the command-line nor via an application-level env var *(e.g. `CATALINA_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` for Tomcat)* ... then as a **last resort**:

- to inject a new property, use env var `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`
- to override a property set internally by the canned app, use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS is the only standard part of all sun JVMs, and some versions of IBM jdk will also read it, but some versions of non-sun jdk could ignore it.

The other variables could be read by many shell scripts, such as tomcat,maven. but it is not a standard way.

So the only standard way is to specify the options in command line, and use a shell script is the widely used way.